# Checksum in cache manifest with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html

I have ASP.NET MVC based mobile web application with cache manifest. This cache manifest includes javascript, css sources and pages itself:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

# version 56517bc4-bb5d-fe72-fb2e-812379ceb0df

CACHE:
/Styles/site.css
/images/flags-euro.png
/mypage1
/mypage2
```

I would like to calculate checksum based on content of every file to maintain cache.manifest versioning (for automatic site updates on the browser side). It's easy to do for static files: read file content and calculate checksum.

But how to do it for pages? I need to get page content by requesting that page and calculate checksum. Any ideas how to do it with ASP.NET MVC?